# Types Enums and Constructors

Tags: haskell, types, enums, constructor

Hello I have the following types:

```
type AlphaOne     = Int
type AlphaTwo     = String
type CharlieOne   = Int
type CharlieTwo   = String
type CharlieThree = Bool

data Sign         = Alpha (AlphaOne, AlphaTwo) |
                    Bravo |
                    Charlie CharlieOne CharlieTwo CharlieThree | 
                    Delta

data Color        = Red | Blue | Green

data Code         = C Sign Color
```

and following function:

```
foo :: Code -> Bool
foo (C sign _)
  | {-1-} sign == Charlie {-1-} = {-2-} do coo "with CharlieTwo of Charlie" {-2-}
  | ...

coo :: Charlie -> Bool
coo (Charlie _ charlieTwo _)
  | ...
```

I marked the line where I have a questions with {-1-} and {-2-} in the code. At {-1-} I get the error "Couldn't match expected type 'Sign' with actual type ‘CharlieOne -> CharlieTwo -> CharlieThree -> Sign'. How can i check if sign equals Charlie in this line of code, and {-2-} how can I access CharlieTwo of Charlie in this function to call another function with CharlieTwo as the parameter?

Have mercy I am new to haskell I might have done something stupid here, thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: voting to close https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This pattern helps you to match on anything with `Charlie`:

```hs
foo :: Code -> Bool
foo (C (Charlie _ _ _) _) = True
```

Running a short test:

```
λ> foo (C (Charlie 1 "hello" True) Red) 
True
```

Your second function has a wrong type signature.

```hs
coo :: Charlie -> Bool
coo (Charlie _ charlieTwo _)
  | ...
```

`Charlie` is a constructor on the term level, but you are using it on the type level. `Charlie` is still of type `Sign`, so you have to change the signature to the following:

```hs
coo :: Sign -> Bool
```

And pattern match on it to access `CharlieTwo`:

```hs
coo :: Sign -> Bool
coo (Charlie _ charlie2 _) =
```